# Triangulating 3D Text

Tags: text-object

Im trying to create a triangulated .obj file with 3D text.
Problem is, after creating the text I can't find a way to properly triangulate it. 
Converting it to a mesh only triangualte parts of it.

Is there a simple way to do something like that?

P.S Im a complete newbie with Blender :S

Thanks

Comment: You probably need to use remesh modifier (http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.62/Remesh_Modifier see text example in the page) and then you can use mesh > faces > triangulate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into edit mode after you create the object from text, select all with <kbd>A</kbd> and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to triangulate. Alternatively, when exporting to obj, there is an option to triangulate on export in the tool shelf.

[image]